# Convert multiple moran.test outputs into structured, storable, copy-pastable strings

Tags: r, report

I wish to collapse the output of `spdep::moran.test` into a single string that is regularly structured with variable names and values and that can both be saved as a text value into a dataframe, and be human readable in the RStudio console and copy-pastable into MS Word to form a table without too many additional manual adjustments. (I have multiple tests to run and wish to copy-paste their output in one go.)

In the course of looking for a solution, I stumbled upon the `report` package which claims to turn an `htest` class object into a "report" (I don't know what this looks like in R) and thus *may* address my goal to some extent. However, the `report` function doesn't work on `moran.test`, as presented in the code below.

I am exploring and there are probably alternative and more straightforward approaches which I haven't considered. Thus my question is twofold: 1. Solve the immediate issue with `report` and/or 2. Provide an alternative and more efficient solution to my goal.

The data preparation below is drawn from https://mgimond.github.io/simple_moransI_example.

```
library(sf)
library(spdep)
library(report)

# Load shapefile
s <- readRDS(url("https://github.com/mgimond/Data/raw/gh-pages/Exercises/nhme.rds"))

# Prevent error "old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()"
st_crs(s) <- st_crs(s)

# Define neighboring polygons
nb <- poly2nb(s, queen=TRUE)

# Assign weights to the neighbors
lw <- nb2listw(nb, style="W", zero.policy=TRUE)

# Run Moran’s I test
(mt <- moran.test(s$Income,lw, alternative="greater"))
#Moran I test under randomisation
#data:  s$Income  
#weights: lw    
#Moran I statistic standard deviate = 5.8525, p-value = 2.421e-09
#alternative hypothesis: greater
#sample estimates:
#  Moran I statistic       Expectation          Variance 
#0.68279551       -0.04000000        0.01525284

# Moran’s I test is of class htest required by function report::report
class(mt)
#[1] "htest"

# Function report::report returns an error
report(mt)
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "tau", value = c(`Moran I statistic` = 0.68279551202875,  : 
#  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

The desired output could look something like:

```
"P-value 2.421e-09 | Statistic 0.68279551 | Expectation -0.04000000 | Variance 0.01525284"
```

The point is the names and values, not the separators. This is based on my current assumptions of how to approach this task, which are probably imperfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `broom` package:

```
broom::tidy(mt)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   estimate1 estimate2 estimate3 statistic    p.value method          alternative
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
#> 1     0.683     -0.04    0.0153      5.85    2.42e-9 Moran I test u… greater

library(tidyverse)
mt %>%
  broom::tidy() %>%
  as.list() %>% 
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(value = value %>% as.character()) %>% unite(data, sep = "=") %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  paste0(collapse = ", ")
#> [1] "estimate1=0.68279551202875, estimate2=-0.04, estimate3=0.0152528397222445, statistic=c(`Moran I statistic standard deviate` = 5.85248209823413), p.value=2.42145194022024e-09, method=Moran I test under randomisation, alternative=greater"
```

You can make a table and create a csv file from multiple tests (e.g. having multiple objects of class `htest` like `mt`, `mt1` and `mt2`):

```
list(mt, mt2, mt3) %>% map(broom::tidy) %>% bind_rows() %>% write_csv("tests.csv")
```